# Which versions of mysql can MySQL Workbench 6.0.9 connect to?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've scoured the MySql website to see if they have compatibility listings for MySQL Workbench, but have not found anything. Does anyone know if 6.0.x can connect to 5.5.x databases? I'd rather not install and then have to roll back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Workbench can connect to most MySQL server versions, but that is probably not the primary question. You should rather ask what minimum version it can **work** with. MySQL Workbench requires at least MySQL 5.0 and can work with any MySQL server after that (including the new 5.7). Some features like authentication plugin or performance schema support require higher server versions, though.

Comment: Yeah I ended up biting the bullet and trying 6.0.9. The new interface when it starts is horrendous. I don't know why they switched to a "Metro" style cards interface.